# SimpleMembership with SQL Server Express database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I have recently discovered that ASP.NET MVC 4 uses SimpleMembership rather than the traditional ASP.NET Membership provider.

I am looking to use SimpleMembership but I also wish to use an Sql Server express database (I will be using a 'real' Sql Server db later on).

I am used to using aspnet_regsql to setup my sql server databases for application services and therefore inserting the necessary membership tables.

However, this application will not setup a DB to work with SimpleMembership.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to comment out the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection line of code (otherwise the first time you reach the login form the application will attempt to create the simple membership tables on the defined web.config connection string).

Then you will need to update your account controller code since its was written for simpleMembership use to reflect your chosen membership provider.

Recently I did this by creating an MVC3 project then upgrading it to MVC4 ([read the how to upgrade mvc3 to mvc4 section](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes)). Not the cleanest but it did prevent me from having to update the account controllers code.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to look into InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute, which is in the folder "Filters"

There is a command to initialize the database. It checks itself, if the tables are already created.

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("connStringName", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

The tables are:

- UserProfile  => in my case, because of the initializer
- webpages_OAuthMembership
- webpages_Membership
- webpages_OAuthToken
- webpages_Roles
- webpages_UsersInRoles

You can check out the source-code of the aspnetwebstack project